Geographical locations of ARINC and SITA ground station
Is there an up-to-date list of ARINC and SITA ground stations?
The German Bundesaufsichtamt für Flugsicherung has published a PDF leaflet which lists various ACARS frequencies, including those for ground stations such as

136.825 MHz VDL Mode 2 GND
136.875 MHz VDL Mode 2 GND
136.925 MHz

Now I'm wondering where those ground stations are located.

Why would you need to know that?

It lists those frequencies that are reserved. It does not say they are in actual use.

There is the plain old ACARS and the FAA Next Gen (VDL2). An overview.
